# Installing Windows Home Server on Dell Studio Hybrid

Tags: windows-home-server, dell-studio

I am wondering if anybody out there had any luck in installing Windows Home Server on a Dell Studio Hybrid.

It always fails at the reboot with an IDE error, I can install Windows Vista / 7 without any issues.

I have upgraded to the latest BIOS firmware too.

Comment: Which version of WHS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

An obvious reason could be that WHS doesn't have the necessary sata/ide drivers, the easiest solution would be to get find the drivers and put on a usb stick and then try installing WHS while having the stick plugged in.

Hope this works

Comment: Agreed. I had a similar issue installing WHS on a HP machine.
Since WHS is based on Windows 2003, you are looking for Windows 2003 compatible drivers.

Comment: And remember that WS2k3 is the server version of WinXP.